# How to create password protected zip file in windows using cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, zip, archiving, password-protection

I am looking to create a password protected zip file in Windows 10 using command prompt.

The closet I've got is this powershell script that creates a zip file without a password. I am then calling it using the cmd which is not ideal.

```
Compress-Archive -Path "path_to_be_zipped" -DestinationPath "zip_destination"
```

Is there any way to do this with the cmd in Windows?

Please note that I cannot install 7-zip and use its commands or any other software for that matter.

Comment: The native ability to compress files, built into Windows, doesn’t support passwords nor encryption. What you want isn’t possible.

Comment: Ah ok, I had this command line tool on my computer called zip (info-zip) and wasn't sure if it is natively shipped with windows 10 or if I had installed it at some point..must have installed it one of this days...

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can use PowerShell and install `7Zip4Powershell` module in order to [create password protected zip file](https://www.byteinthesky.com/powershell/how-to-zip-and-unzip-file-with-password/#using-7zip4powershell-module) without having to install 7-Zip software.

For example,

```
Compress-7Zip -Path 'C:\Scripts\' -ArchiveFileName 'Test.zip' -OutputPath 'C:\Archives\' -Format Zip -SecurePassword (Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString)
```

Above script will add to archive `C:\Scripts\` directory and all its files recursively, then store the file in `C:\Archives\` with `Test.zip` as the zip file name.

You can explore the syntax and its capabilities in [github repository](https://github.com/thoemmi/7Zip4Powershell) which is approximately the same with 7-Zip software.